# ArgumentError on Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to run the Ruby code below but I keep on getting the following error:

Failed: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

stacktrace:  ./basic_read_write.rb:3:in `write_data_to_file'
/tmp/test.rb:5:in`block (2 levels) in

```
# writes the number of lines then each line as a string.

def write_data_to_file()
   a_file=File.new("mydata.txt","w")
   a_file.puts('5')
   a_file.puts('Fred')
   a_file.puts('Sam')
   a_file.puts('Jill')
   a_file.puts('Jenny')
   a_file.puts('Zorro')
   a_file.close

end


def read_data_from_file()
  a_file=File.new("mydata.txt","r")

  count = a_file.gets.to_i
  puts count.to_s
  for i in 0..count.to_i
    puts a_file.gets
  end 
  a_file.close


def main
  # open for writing
  write_data_to_file()


   # open for reading
  read_data_from_file()

end

main
end
```

Comment: Could you provide the whole backtrace?

Comment: Please provide valid, runnable code. (Your code above contains an extra `end`.) And please *always* show the **full** error message; don't try to truncate it to be "helpful"; you've actually deleted some of the most important information!

Comment: @MasafumiOkura I have added the stacktrace to the original post. I hope that helps!

Comment: I copied your code and no error occurred. Are you sure that you paste the code you have some problem with?

Comment: @ibz95 Your code still isn't valid; your stacktrace is still truncated, and your code (once the "obvious" syntax issue is fixed) still doesn't appear to contain any error. Please try again to create a [mcve] of the problem, otherwise unfortunately no one is going to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

The above code looks good except for the end statement in the methods. Every method ends with end.
According to your code, the def read_data_from_file() has an end at the end after the def main.

```
def write_data_to_file()
   a_file=File.new("mydata.txt","w")
   a_file.puts('5')
   a_file.puts('Fred')
   a_file.puts('Sam')
   a_file.puts('Jill')
   a_file.puts('Jenny')
   a_file.puts('Zorro')
   a_file.close

end


def read_data_from_file()
  a_file=File.new("mydata.txt","r")

  count = a_file.gets.to_i
  puts count.to_s
  for i in 0..count.to_i
    puts a_file.gets
  end 
  a_file.close
end

def main
  # open for writing
  write_data_to_file()


   # open for reading
  read_data_from_file()

end

main
```

Comment: But a missing `end` keyword wouldn't raise an `ArgumentError`

Comment: ArgumentError comes up when a method  declaration for example ` def test(parameter) ` and when we are calling this method `test("file.txt", "r")` Then, this will throw error as the parameters dont count. But in the above code, there is nothing which would create this error.